# Will Redis 6 guarantee client requests order?

Tags: database, serialization, redis

Are all requests from a give client are executed and reply in the order that they were sent by the client?

As we know, Redis 6 provided threaded IO, so when I send Redis some requests through one client, are those requests executed and reply in the same order I send?

And how Redis makes such guarantee?

Comment: I can't give a comprehensive answer, but here's the description from [redis.conf](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/bdd541174736522c92ff786576e744269c3a1c2c/redis.conf#L972).